# Any Ideas on integrating Vaadin with bootstrap or Popper tooltips?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, vaadin

Just like in the topic, I'm looking for some clean solution for integrating Bootstrap v3 tooltips with Vaadin.

Instead of Button.setDescription i'd like to use Boostrap style tootpis.

Any ideas since there is no way to manage coustom html properties in Vaadin?

Comment: I think it would be easier in Vaadin 10 (flow) to have custom tool tips. For Vaadin 8, you will need to code your own client-side extension as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

In Vaadin 8 you can integrate custom web component using https://vaadin.com/directory/component/elements-add-on